# How can I use i++ and ++i from C in Lua

Tags: lua

Is there a way to use `i++` instead of `i = i + 1` in Lua? <strike>I think it might be possible since Lua can use C functions directly.</strike>

Comment: `++` is not a C function, it is an operator.  So Lua being able to use C functions is not applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855525/simulate-in-lua-is-it-possible.

Comment: not necessarily - I'm curious whether there is any hacky way of achieving `i++` in Lua. Thanks anyway. `increment` function is a way around somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid typing, see if your editor can expand `++i` to `i = i + 1` for you.

If you just want a hacky way that doesn't involve modifying the Lua source code then tables will get you pass-by-reference and the `__call` meta-method can be used as an expression or statement.

```
function num(v)
  local t = {v or 0}
  function postinc(t, i)
    local old = t[1]
    t[1] = t[1] + (i or 1)
    return old
  end
  setmetatable(t, {__call=postinc})
  return t
end


i = num()
print(i())  -- print(i++)
i()         -- i++
print(i(0)) -- print(i)
```

Writing code like this is never worth it, accessing the "value" of `i` now requires `i(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to modify the parser to accept `++`, since it's not part of the syntax. Creating a new incompatible dialect of Lua just to save a few characters just isn't worth it, though.

Defining some sort of a function for this won't work in general either, since functions in Lua are pass-by-value, so you'd have to write

```
i = incr(i)
```

which pretty much defeats the point, and doesn't let you express `++i` anyway.

Maybe you could do `incr 'variableName'` and mess with the local environment of the calling function... but again, that's just overcomplicated, not worth the trouble and generally a horrible idea in every way imaginable.

Answer (score 3):

While you can't do `i++` or `++i` in Lua by default you can change `i = i + 1` to `i += 1` which is much better

Comment: "which is much better"—how is it much better?

Comment: @Chris `VeryLongVariableName = VeryLongVariableName + 1` is at least one `VeryLongVariableName` better by my counting.